# how to make a very large radmind image, faster

Tags: files

Making the new Snow Leopard radmind image* for my lab involves manipulating over 50GB of applications, including passing them over the network. Each try takes four hours or more, and if it fails there's no apparent way to pick up again from partway through. Instead I have to delete all the data (a minutes-long operation) and start over. Furthermore, one successful upload just means now I get to test whether the image works; if it doesn't, I can look forward to repeating the upload as many times as I need to troubleshoot.

How can I do this faster and/or smarter?

Answer (score 2):

With Radmind it's faster and easier to create individual loadsets for each application (or suite of applications) rather than one huge loadset.  It also has the benefit that if you want to uninstall software all you need to do is remove it from the command file and the associated files will be removed from the machine after the next scan.

To start you would create a base loadset that contains the base OS files and applications.  After this has been created you can apply it to a test machine to verify that the computer reboots afterwards and that nothing bad goes wrong.  Then you can start working on creating each application loadset and testing them.

Our base OS 10.5 install is around 7 GB right now and then we start layering on the applications (Office 2008, CS4).